# Where to find webview-command-line for retrieving netlogs

Tags: chrome-for-android, webview

I need to get netlogs for the Android webview used by my application.
The chromium describes few steps to do so. It required userdebug build for which I am using emulator.

But the commandline flags need to set using webview-command-line . The path `/data/local/tmp/webview-command-line` doesn't exists.
There is nothing inside. `/data/local/tmp` folder.

Can someone please guide me to how set the commandline flags.

Regards

Comment: Launch WebView DevTools by running: `adb shell am start -a com.android.webview.SHOW_DEV_UI` and enable `webview-verbose-logging` flag. But I think this flag won't be available on final `user` builds.

Comment: Have you tried to just create the file `/data/local/tmp/webview-command-line` and place the command-line options in it? See here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/commandline-flags.md